# Creating/Reloading dynamic express folders in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create files and place them into a folder, then send a link to the Microsoft Emotion API.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '4mb'}));

app.use('/pics', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'pics')))
app.post('/face', function(req, res){
    var base64Data = req.body.img.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    var id;
    fs.readdir("./pics", (err, files) => {
        id = files.length;
        fs.writeFile(`./pics/${id}.png`, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            reload(http, app);
            setTimeout(function(){
                fetch(`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize`, {
                    method: "POST",
                    data: `{"url": "${"https://{ngrok-id}.ngrok.io/pics/"+id+".png"}"}`,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{api-key}'
                    }
                }).then(function(data) {
                    return data.json();
                }).then(function(data){
                    console.log(`{"url": "${"https://{ngrok-id}.ngrok.io/pics/"+id+".png"}"}`);
                    res.json(data);
                });
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a way to make express folders dynamic or reload static folders?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the term static. In short it means:

> Static [assets] are things that don't change.

Key words: **don't change**. As of now, your logic says you will be mutating files in a folder which is supposed to be static. Don't do that.

Create or use a different path to mutate files. There is no way to "reload folders", static or not. You have to explicitly read from the folder which you are doing now via `fs.readdir`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to experiment with:
https://nodemon.io

This will reload your entire application, when content in it changes.

This tool is built for development purpose, I have never tried it in production. But maybe it fits your needs.